# ¿Por qué da error de seguridad con localStorage en los snippets?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Ahora mismo acabo de responder a una pregunta sobre JavaScript basada en `localStorage`, ya en el pasado había visto que SO no permite crear fragmentos de código basados en esta API, dando un error de seguridad.

Viendo que sitios como JSFiddle sí permiten probar código de este tipo, me pregunto:

- ¿Por qué SO es tan restrictivo en ese aspecto? No parecería que permitir `localStorage` suponga un riesgo mayor para nadie ... ¿ o sí?
- ¿Habría alguna forma de hacer que fragmentos de código funcionaran en el caso concreto de `localStorage`?

Answer (score 8):

> ¿Por qué SO es tan restrictivo en ese aspecto? No parecería que permitir localStorage suponga un riesgo mayor para nadie ... ¿ o sí?

En realidad, no es problema de SO, **es problema de seguridad, pues los snippets son un iframe**, en distintas ocasiones he tenido problemas de conexión y he visto que los *snippets* están en un `iframe`, entonces esto es una excepción de seguridad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
localStorage
```

Como puedes ver dice *stacksnippets*, lo que quiere decir que es un elemento vinculado a la página a través de un *iframe*, por lo tanto es un problema de seguridad y no de los snippets de SO

Además, si inspeccionas el elemento puedes verlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no solo sucede en SO, también sucede en cualquier otro servicio que vincule un iframe y se intente usar métodos que hagan cómplice a la ventana actual, pues el *iframe* no tiene control sobre la ventana actual, debido a que es una ventana vinculada

> ¿Habría alguna forma de hacer que fragmentos de código funcionaran en el caso concreto de localStorage?

Hay soluciones sencillas, si el servidor provee un encabezado correcto (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`), el compartimiento de ventanas será posible

Si ambos servidores no responden con el encabezado correcto, no hay forma compartir, modificar ni obtener los elementos en *localStorage*, *sessionStorage* ni otros servicios que funcionen en la ventana actual

---

Finalmente, en el servicio de [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkt5x03j/), el código funciona porque el servidor responde con los encabezados correctos

```html
<iframe src="https://moonlit-accountabil.000webhostapp.com/code/"></iframe>
```

Como puedes ver, da el mismo problema, no lo dice directamente, pero si inspeccionas el elemento verás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es básicamente un problema de compartimiento de cookies, una ventana que está anclada en otra no podrá generar cookies, a menos que la ventana principal se lo permita

Al acceder directamente a la página, detecta el log, ya que es del mismo origen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te metes a insertar un snippet, y dentro del mismo snippet intentas dibujar un iframe al mismo dominio, no te dejará. Pero no es problema de q

Comment: Sino de CSP. Perdonen pero estoy en el móvil y de verdad soy bien torpe con letritas chicas

Comment: @ffflabs Gracias por el aporte, no soy experto en _headers_ y al buscar _"allow-same-origin"_, lo primero que salió fue algo relacionado con CORS, entonces pensé que estaba vinculado con ese tema

Comment: Esta es una respuesta muy útil. He aprendido algo nuevo. No se me había presentado ese problema antes, pero, tampoco estaba consciencia de eso.

Answer (score 2):

Los motivos ya los dio @anythingg, así que aporto una solución: implementar tu propio localStorage en el fragmento, pero tienes el problema de que añade *ruido* a cualquier respuesta.

Obviamente no hay posibilidad de persistir los datos, pero de todos modos creo que eso estaría fuera de las necesidades de un fragmento,

```js
class Storage {
  constructor() { this.items = {}; }
  getItem(key) { return this.items[key]; }
  removeItem(key) { delete this.items[key]; }
  setItem(key, value) { this.items[key]=value.toString(); }//sólo strings
  key(index) { return Object.keys(this.items)[index]; }
}

//window.localStorage es "read-only", no podemos sobreescribirla
window.fakeStorage = new Storage();
fakeStorage.setItem('test','value');
console.log(fakeStorage.getItem('test'));
    console.log(fakeStorage.key(0));
fakeStorage.removeItem('test');
console.log(fakeStorage.getItem('test'));
```